# How to call model function into controller nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am completely new to nodejs want to understand how we can create
model function in mvc architecture. I create mvc architecture but
want to know how we can call model function to Controller

Answer (score 5):

Create function in model file and export it...

In controller file require that model file and by its object you can call that function defined in model...

**model.js**

```
exports.hi = function(){
    console.log("hi");
}
```

**controller.js**

```
var model = require('model');
model.hi();
```